# remove all record of a model in Django restfull

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to remove all records of a model by using API but I get an error
how can I do that

View :

```
@api_view(["DELETE"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def delete_site(request):
    try:
        Site.objects.all().delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something went wrong'}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

URL

```
router.register('site-delete',views.delete_site)
```

Error :

```
    assert queryset is not None, '`basename` argument not specified, and could ' \
AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use routers you need to use ViewSets, not function based views.

Change your url config to be a path instead:

```
path(
    "site-delete",
    view= views.delete_site,
    name="delete_site",
),
```

Or refactor your view as a [ViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Answer (score 0):

API for delete all record in a model

View :

```
@api_view(["DELETE"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def delete_site(request):
    user = request.user.id
    try:
        evnt = Site.objects.all()
        evnt.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something went wrong'}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Add View to router.urls

```
urlpatterns = [

    # Site
    path('sitedelete/', views.delete_site, name='sitedelete')
    ]+router.urls
```